# AngularJS ng-bind select text not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So i'm currently creating a new application with Angularjs, Prestashop webservice and some HTML, PHP, etc.

Suddenly i stumbled upon a problem while creating the cart and checkout system

1. All the products are selected from the Database.
2. The products can be added to the cart through a button.
3. The button is an ng-click function.

The problem i'm having is selecting the input of an element, like the product name.

See the code below.

```js
    $scope.addToCart = function(){
  // info is in the table / single product layout
  var id = $(this).find('h5.product-id').text();
  var product_name = $(this).find('h5.product_name').text();
  var product_price = $(this).find('h5.product_price').text();
  var product_size = $(this).find('h5.product_size').text();
  var quantity = $(this).find('h5.product_quantity').val();
  // redirect to add_to_cart.php, with parameer values to process the request
        alert($(this).find("h5.product_name").text());
  /*
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
            data:{id:id, product_name:product_name,product:product_price, product_size:product_size, quantity:quantity},
            url:"config/cart/addCart.php" // PHP Page URL To php code saving the input to the database
        });
        */
    };
```

```html
<div class="container">
                            <form>
                                <div class="row hidden">
                                    <div class="col-12 product text-center">
                                        <h5 class="product_id" ng-bind="product.id"></h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12 product text-center">
                                        <h5 class="product_name" ng-bind="product.name"></h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="no-padding col-6">
                                        <h5>{{ 'Prijs' | translate }}</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="no-padding product col-6" data-name="{{product.price}}" >
                                        <h5 class="product_price" ng-bind="product.price"></h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="no-padding col-6">
                                        <h5>{{ 'Totale voorraad' | translate }}</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="no-padding product col-6" ng-if="product.id == stock_available.id" ng-repeat="stock_available in stock_availables">
                                        <h5 ng-bind="stock_available.quantity"></h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="no-padding col-6">
                                        <h5>{{ 'Kies uw maat' | translate }}</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="no-padding product col-6">
                                        <h5 class="product_size">S</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="no-padding col-6">
                                        <h5>{{ 'Kies aantal' | translate }}</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="no-padding product col-6">
                                        <h5 class="product_quantity">2</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <button ng-click="addToCart()" type="submit">
                                            Toevoegen aan winkelwagen
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Don't mind the `$.ajax` request since it's in comments.

First i wanted to test the selection so i've came up with a simple `alert`. The problem i'm having is that the `alert()` is empty.

1. Yes i've checked other questions and answers on stack but they didn't work for me.
2. Yes i did check if the data is loaded, and the right controller is selected.

Hope someone has a good solution.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have `'h3.product_price'` while your tag is `<h5>`. Also you should avoid using jQuery with Angularjs

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I've seen the `h5` and `h3` errors and fixed them, Do you have a solution on how i should do it?

Comment: You should not read data from the DOM directly (like you do with `$(this).find(..)` in `addToCart`. Instead you should work with the bound variables in the controller functions. You have already bound the content of the h5 tags to `product.xxx`. You can reuse those in the controller

Comment: @MikaS Could you give an example?

Comment: You have a variable called `product.name` bound to a h5 tag in the html file. I'm not sure exactly where you get this variable from, but I assume it's from a part of the code not included in your question. In `addToCart` you read directly from the html file, while you can do `var product_name = product.name` instead. This is assuming you have `product.name` available in that function. You should also not use `$.ajax` but `$http.post()`. See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for more info on that.

Comment: product.name Comes from a `DB response data` function that calles all product rows from the `products` table. In this case `product.name` stands for the `product name` out of the `products table`. It's a prestashop webservice application i'm working on. @MikaS, Will take a look at the post

Comment: @MikaS So the variable simply calling again would: 1. be stupid since it already exists. 2. Isn't possible since it isn't a variable. Thanks for trying tho!